# Why does as.numeric add decimal places when converting a character?

Tags: r, decimal, rounding, precision

The first line gives me 0.1 and the second line gives me 0.10000000000000001.
Why does this happen? Is rounding a viable solution? Or is there a more precise solution?
I would expect the first line to be "0.1" and the second line to be 0.1.

```r
print(input[[nm]][[i+j]])
print(as.numeric(input[[nm]][[i+j]]))
[1] "0.1"
[1] 0.10000000000000001
```

Comment: Show us the results and what you are expecting

Comment: This is probably a floating point issue.  I'd suggest reading CIRCLE 1. FALLING INTO THE FLOATING POINT TRAP in the freely available book the R Inferno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the `digits` setting in your options. `options("digits")` will tell you the current value, `options(digits=8)` (for example) will set the value.  The "extra" values at the end are due to floating-point error (see Chapter 1 of [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) or search Stack Overflow for question about floating point, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).  (Note that this doesn't change the *underlying value*, just the way it is printed.)

It's impossible to express 0.1 *exactly* in binary floating-point representation.

Here's what gets printed with different digits settings (it looks like you must have `digits` set to 17 ...)

```r
x <- "0.1"
for (i in 1:20) print(c(i,as.numeric(x)), digits=i)
[1] 1.0 0.1
[1] 2.0 0.1
[1] 3.0 0.1
[1] 4.0 0.1
[1] 5.0 0.1
[1] 6.0 0.1
[1] 7.0 0.1
[1] 8.0 0.1
[1] 9.0 0.1
[1] 10.0  0.1
[1] 11.0  0.1
[1] 12.0  0.1
[1] 13.0  0.1
[1] 14.0  0.1
[1] 15.0  0.1
[1] 16.0  0.1
[1] 17.00000000000000000  0.10000000000000001
[1] 18.000000000000000000  0.100000000000000006
[1] 19.0000000000000000000  0.1000000000000000056
[1] 20.00000000000000000000  0.10000000000000000555
```

As you suggest in your comment, you can use `all.equal()` to test for *approximate* equality.  `as.numeric(x)==0.1` is `TRUE`, as is `all.equal(as.numeric(x),0.1)`.  You can adjust the tolerance of `all.equal()`:

```r
z1 <- 0.1
z2 <- z1 + 1e-14
all.equal(z1,z2) ## TRUE
all.equal(z1,z2,tolerance=1e-15)
## [1] "Mean relative difference: 1.000589e-13"
isTRUE(all.equal(z1,z2,tolerance=1e-15)) ## FALSE
```

Comment: Ya I understand that, thanks. But then how do I test for equality? == is returning false and all.equal is returning true even if they are quite far from being equal

Comment: I've tried to answer your second question. (Please note that my answer *does* answer the question you actually asked, I think ...) For new questions, it's best to post a brand-new question, otherwise you risk the original turning into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) ...